# Skype account gets automatically logged out in Flatpak version

Tags: flatpak, skype

In the Flatpak version of Skype, when the app gets closed, my account automatically gets logged out. So, I have to re-enter the credentials each time I open the Skype app.

I have seen this issue only in the Flatpak version, not in the Deb or RPM version(I have not tried the Snap version yet, so I can't tell about that).

Is there any way to troubleshoot this issue?